# How to complete delete old programm pathes. SDK location

Tags: android, linux, path, sdk

I manually install(double click on downloaded pakage -> install button in my linux mint) Android Studio. Setted up the environment. And then i tried to run

```
npx react-native run-android
```

i got "No SDK found at the specified location" and "No emulators found". But i could run emulator manually in Android Studio with some example projects.
I suffered couple hours. And  from command `flutter doctor -v` i saw diferent pathes

```
Android SDK at /usr/lib/android-sdk 
Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
```

These paths are different from those where I installed. My SDK at `/home/some_word/android/sdk` path for example.
And editing $PATH in the .bashrk and .profile files doesn't change the paths I've seen in flutter doctor.
So how can i change this old program pathes?
Or how do I securely uninstall a program so that its paths are completely cleared?

Comment: You can try to set the following environment variables: `ANDROID_HOME` or `ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` for the Android SDK directory. The PATH variable is usually not sued for detecting where Android SDK is installed.

Comment: I did that. `echo $ANDROID_SDK_ROOT` returns proper path but it doesnt change pathes in `flutter doctor -v` and doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

it's enough to completely unistall

```
sudo apt-get purge package_name
```